# R AUC never less than 0.5?

Tags: r, random-forest, auc

I'm doing some work with random forests in R using the `randomForest` package, and I've run into something that seems odd to me. Even when the data is completely random, the AUC is never less than 0.5. For example, when I run the following:

```
library(randomForest)
df.sanity <- data.frame(A=sample(1:100, 2000, replace=T), B=sample(126:159, 2000, replace=T), C=sample(10:2000, 1000, replace=T), D=sample(1:2, 2000, replace=T), E=sample(30:40, 2000, replace=T), Class=as.factor(sample(0:1, 2000, replace=T)))
rf <- randomForest(x=df.sanity[1:1000,c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")], y=df.sanity[1:1000, "Class"])
preds <- predict(rf, newdata=df.sanity[1001:2000,], type="prob")
auc(obs=df.sanity[1001:2000, "Class"], pred=preds[,2])
```

No matter how many times I run it, the AUC is never less than 0.5. It's often a bit over (up to 0.54 from what I've seen), but never less.

The only other AUC implementation I've used is Weka's, and I've seen AUCs < 0.5 there.  Does the `randomForest` package automatically flip the predictions to the reverse if the AUC is ever less than 0.5, or is there something else I'm misunderstanding here?

Comment: That's a good point.  Unfortunately, I'm at work right now on a controlled computer, so I can't install weka now.  I can try when I get home.

Comment: I am not sure whether my comment helps but once I had to write something about statistical comparison of credit default forecasts. And I also used ROC curves and calculated the AUC. I remember from the theory I read, when the two groups are independent and totally random, such that one cannot predict (whether a person belongs to 0 or 1) anything with a model,the distributions of the predicted values are almost equal. Hence, one cannot improve the model - no matter what threshold is chosen - because your ROC curve is then a straight line from 0 to 1. That is the same as saying AUC = 0.5

Comment: Which package is the `auc()` function you used (there is no `auc()` function in the `randomForest` package)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `auc()` function in the `randomForest` package. But based on the argument names you used (`obs` and `pred`), I think you might have used the `auc()` function in the `SDMTools` package. And yes, this function does flip the results if the calculated AUC is less than 0.5:

```
> SDMTools::auc
function (obs, pred) 
{
    … code to calculate the AUC …
    if (AUC < 0.5) 
        AUC = 1 - AUC
    return(AUC)
}
```

This might be seen as a nice convenience feature (it’s easy to forget exactly how AUC functions want their arguments coded, and if you get an AUC < .5 in real life, you have usually just used the inverse/incorrect coding of the response vector ), but I think it’s a bad idea. If you try models that are (almost) as bad as random, e.g., in simulations, you will get estimates that are biased high (compared the ‘correct’ AUC estimator).

If you want the correct AUC estimates, you can use either

- `ROC()` from the `Epi` packages. It draws a nice ROC plot, with the AUC embedded, and also returns an object with the AUC stored as the `AUC` element.
- `rcorr.sens()` from the `rms` package. It returns a list with the AUC stored as the first element.
- `roc()` from the `pROC` package *if* you manually specify the `direction` argument. It returns an object with the AUC stored as the `auc` element.